# Why do we use fetch() while using PDO::query()?

Tags: php, pdo

So, we know that `PDO::query()` returns `PDOStatement object` and the `PDOStatement` class implements `Traversable` so it allows us to loop through it's object using `foreach` loop:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbusername, dbpassword);
$sql = 'SELECT name, surname, gender FROM students';
$stmt = $db->query($sql);

foreach($stmt as $row){
    echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
    echo $row['surname'] . "<br>";
    echo $row['gender'] . "<br>";
}
```

The code is nice and clean. (I know that due to the security issues using `query()` can create and we all should be faithful to `prepare()` and `excecute()` for that.)

My question is why do we bother to use `fetch()` to retrieve data when we can get the same result without using it. It seems to me an extra step.

Comment: There's no mention of whether you *should* use it. It's there so you *can* use it if you want to. There's also `fetchAll()` method so you can also perform `$rows = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll()` and then you have the 3rd approach, where all the records are in the array which you can then loop at your convenience.

Comment: It seems to me an extra step to use `fetch` or `fetchAll` here though i'm not sure

Comment: Why would it be an extra step? Using `fetch` or `fetchAll`, you can create methods that return arrays of data. If you were to return a `$stmt`, that's an instance of `PDOStatement`. Even though the statement implements `Traversable`, it doesn't mean it's the same thing as a plain array. We have these methods at our disposal for our convenience. For example, I would never use what you are using. You might not use what I'm using. But, both of us can use the approach we prefer and achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks dude, that's actually my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because there are queries that return only one row, for which a foreach loop would be an *extra step*.
2. Because traversable PDOStatement is just a syntax sugar, *just another way to do it*, for anyone who like it this way. While `fetch()` remains most familiar and straightforward method.